# #Vue2 Como obter os inputs de uma linha da tabela Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Minha tabela é essa a baixo, não coloquei variáveis porque acho que não precisa.
Eu só quero entender como obter todos os inputs de uma linha quanto eu clicar no botão da mesma linha pra mim poder enviar com axios.post.

```
<v-simple-table dense>
       <template v-slot:default>
          <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th class="text-left">ID</th>
                  <th class="text-left">Nome</th>
                  <th class="text-left">Marca</th>
                  <th class="text-left">Ações</th>
               </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr v-for="(item, index) in carros">
            <td>
                {{item.id}}
            </td>   
            <td>
                <v-text-field></v-text-field>
            </td>
            <td>
                <v-text-field></v-text-field>
            </td>

            <td>
               <v-btn small class="ma-2" color="primary" dark>
                 <i class="material-icons">
                   check_circle
                 </i>
               </v-btn>
            </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
       </template>
    </v-simple-table>
```

Não sei se preciso passas algum id para os inputs.. gostaria de saber.
Obrigado desde já pela atenção!

Comment: Tem que montar o exemplo completo minimo, não tem como saber dessa forma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é preciso adicionar `id` nos `inputs`.

Use `v-model` nos `inputs` e depois pegue o valor que precisar em um `method` que é acionado ao clicar no botão.

Dê uma olhada neste exemplo, acho que pode te ajudar.

```js
new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
       carros: [
       {id: 1, nome: "Carro 1", marca: "Marca A"},
       {id: 1, nome: "Carro 2", marca: "Marca B"},
       {id: 1, nome: "Carro 3", marca: "Marca C"}
       ]
      },
      methods: {
      get(item) {
          console.log("valor input 1 => ", item.nome, " valor input 2 => ", item.marca);
        }
      },
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
 
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
<v-simple-table dense>
       <template v-slot:default>
          <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th class="text-left">ID</th>
                  <th class="text-left">Nome</th>
                  <th class="text-left">Marca</th>
                  <th class="text-left">Ações</th>
               </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr v-for="(item, index) in carros" :key="index">
            <td>
                {{item.id}}
            </td>   
            <td>
                <v-text-field v-model="item.nome"></v-text-field>
            </td>
            <td>
                <v-text-field v-model="item.marca"></v-text-field>
            </td>

            <td>
               <v-btn @click="get(item)" small class="ma-2" color="primary" dark>
                 get
               </v-btn>
            </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
       </template>
    </v-simple-table>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado! 
Era só isso que eu precisava saber!